# Use mORMot Framework to send message between server and clients

Tags: delphi, mormot

mORMot Framework ([www.synopse.info](http://www.synopse.info)) have add support to WebSockets, on pack there is also a demo about WebSockets (sample 31). In this sample the client send a message to server and this reply with a new message to client.
I'd like use this library to do this:

1. The client send message to server and send also the IP address (without waiting message from server.);
2. The server can send message to single client by IP address;

Note: the IP address is used only to identify the client. I can use also a unique name.

Something like a LAN chat between clients and server. I don't understand how edit the sample n. 31 to do it. This sample is based on interface.

Comment: The link to the framework should be synopse.info (not .com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No need to store the IP, or whatever low-level implementation parameter (by the way, the IP would not be able to identify a connection in an unique manner: several clients may share the same IP).

In the *mORMot* framework, asynchronous callbacks are implemented via interface parameters. On the server side, each instance of this parameter would be in fact a "fake" class instance, linked to the input connection, able to call back the client via its interface methods.

This is a pretty straightforward way of implementing callbacks - in fact this is a good way of implementing SOLID callbacks on the server side, and the *mORMot* framework allows to publish this mechanism in a client/server way, by using *WebSockets*.

So you first define the callback interface, and the service interface:

```
  IChatCallback = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{EA7EFE51-3EBA-4047-A356-253374518D1D}']
    procedure BlaBla(const pseudo, msg: string);
  end;

  IChatService = interface(IInvokable)
    ['{C92DCBEA-C680-40BD-8D9C-3E6F2ED9C9CF}']
    procedure Join(const pseudo: string; const callback: IChatCallback);
    procedure BlaBla(const pseudo,msg: string);
    procedure CallbackReleased(const callback: IInvokable);
  end;
```

Then, on the server side, each call to `IChatService.Join()` would *subscribe* to an internal list of connections:

```
  TChatService = class(TInterfacedObject,IChatService)
  protected
    fConnected: array of IChatCallback;
  public
    procedure Join(const pseudo: string; const callback: IChatCallback);
    procedure BlaBla(const pseudo,msg: string);
    procedure CallbackReleased(const callback: IInvokable);
  end;

procedure TChatService.Join(const pseudo: string;
  const callback: IChatCallback);
begin
  InterfaceArrayAdd(fConnected,callback);
end;
```

Then a remote call to the `IChatService.BlaBla()` method should be broadcasted to all connected clients, just by calling the `IChatCallback.BlaBla()` method:

```
procedure TChatService.BlaBla(const pseudo,msg: string);
var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(fConnected) do
    fConnected[i].BlaBla(pseudo,msg);
end;
```

Note that all the loop calls to `IChatCallback.BlaBla()` would be made via *WebSockets*, in an asynchronous and non blocking way, so that even in case of huge number of clients, the `IChatService.BlaBla()` method won't block. In case of high numbers of messages, the framework is even able to *gather* push notification messages into a single message, to reduce the resource use.

The following method will be called by the server, when a client callback instance is released (either explicitly, or if the connection is broken), so could be used to *unsubscribe* to the notification:

```
procedure TChatService.CallbackReleased(const callback: IInvokable);
begin
  InterfaceArrayDelete(fConnected,callback);
end;
```

On the server side, you define the service as such:

```
  Server.ServiceDefine(TChatService,[IChatService],sicShared).
    SetOptions([],[optExecLockedPerInterface]);
```

Here, the `optExecLockedPerInterface` option has been set, so that all method calls would be made thread-safe, so that concurrent access to the internal `fConnected[]` list would be safe.

On the client side, you implement the `IChatCallback` callback interface:

```
type
  TChatCallback = class(TInterfacedCallback,IChatCallback)
  protected
    procedure BlaBla(const pseudo, msg: string);
  end;

procedure TChatCallback.BlaBla(const pseudo, msg: string);
begin
  writeln(#13'@',pseudo,' ',msg);
end;
```

Then you *subscribe* to your remote service as such:

```
var Service: IChatService;
    callback: IChatCallback;
...
    Client.ServiceDefine([IChatService],sicShared);
    if not Client.Services.Resolve(IChatService,Service) then
      raise EServiceException.Create('Service IChatService unavailable');
...
      callback := TChatCallback.Create(Client,IChatCallback);
      Service.Join(pseudo,callback);
...
    try
      repeat
        TextColor(ccLightGray);
        readln(msg);
        if msg='' then
          break;
        Service.BlaBla(pseudo,msg);
      until false;
    finally
      callback := nil;
      Service := nil; // release the service local instance BEFORE Client.Free
    end;
```

If you compare with existing client/server SOA solutions (in Delphi, Java, C# or even in Go or other frameworks), this interface-based callback mechanism sounds pretty unique and easy to work with. Of course, this work from Delphi 6 up to XE7, and also under Linux thanks to FPC or CrossKylix.

I've uploaded the full sample source code in our repository, both [the server side application](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/Samples/31%20-%20WebSockets/Project31ChatServer.dpr) and [the client side](https://github.com/synopse/mORMot/blob/master/SQLite3/Samples/31%20-%20WebSockets/Project31ChatClient.dpr).

Comment: I've written a blog article http://blog.synopse.info/post/2015/04/06/Asynchronous-Service-WebSockets%2C-Callbacks-and-Publish-Subscribe
And also added some dedicated documentation, which should be used as reference - see http://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_149